# Link route to directive? Or another way?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-routing

I have an unusual question.

I have this old page that I want to convert to angular.js.

http://transience.me/TD/

I have 5 pages worth of html loaded on one page and the only visible portion is the part that has been navigated to. i.e. **home** is at x position 0, **about** is at x position, 1024, **projects** is at x position 2048, etc...

Right now though there's no way to link to the individual sections. You have to land at the home and then navigate to the section you want to visit.

However I want to add a deep linked url: url/#/home, url/#/project, etc.. to correspond with the navigation which triggers a change in page position.

Is there a way to link the router in angularjs to a directive so that instead of loading an html template it triggers a new dom behavior?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) would help you greatly.

It uses a $stateProvider which allows you to change the url without reloading the entire template. You can add transition effects and to move between pages and it will keep all back buttons, page refreshes, etc.

Check out the [ui-router demo](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/)

Comment: That looks awesome. Thanks!

What is angular-ui? Like an plugin for angular?